# Please provide a raw object to `props.sceneStyle` instead of a StyleSheet reference

Tags: javascript, react-native

I figured out the answer to this question on my own, but I'm posting the question here so that the future Googler can find it easily and get the solution to the problem.

The problem came when using the deprecated Navigator component, and when using the 'sceneStyle' property.  My original Navigator component looked like this:

```
<Navigator 
    initialRoute={routes.main}
    renderScene={this._renderScene}
    style={styles.container}
    sceneStyle={styles.sceneContainer}
  />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  sceneContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
})
```

The following gave me the following error:

`Invariant violation: error when using Navigator from react-native-custom-components. Please provide a raw object to props.sceneStyle instead of a StyleSheet reference`

Answer (score 0):

In order to correct the error, I had to change the code to the following:

```
<Navigator 
    initialRoute={routes.main}
    renderScene={this._renderScene}
    style={styles.container}
    sceneStyle={{
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'stretch'
    }}
  />
```

And that removed the error and allowed the navigator component to function normally.